# Why can't a set a mockito mock to a field of a autowired initialized spring bean?

Tags: spring, mockito

Naively I thought I could set a mockito to un already initialized spring bean.  When I do that somewhere along the way the bean is getting back the original spring injected  value.

Is there no other way than injecting the mock thru xml or java spring config?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the Mock anotation and use InjectMocks annotation on the object that uses the dependency. Or the classic way is to use Mockito.mock(MyClassOrInterface.class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about integration tests that you run e.g. with '@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)'. In unit tests you would not usually deal with Spring - this is the advantage of Spring and DI.

I usually override the production configuration with test configuration using the following:

- To override @Autowired/@Injected bean, mark your beans in the test configurations as @Primary
- To override beans injection by name, use aliases in your test configuration (see an example below)

Your production config:

```
@Configuration
class ProdConfig {
     @Bean Abc abc() { return new AbcImpl(); }
     @Bean Xyz xyz() { return new XyzImpl(); }
}
class SomeBean {
    @Inject Abc abc;
    @Resource(name="xyz") Xyz xys;
}
```

Your test config:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ProdConfig.class)
class TestConfig {
     @Primary
     @Bean(name={"abcOverride", "abc"}) 
     Abc abc() { 
        return Mockito.mock(Abc.class); 
     }
     @Primary
     @Bean(name={"xyzOverride", "xyz"}) 
     Xyz xyz() { 
        return Mockito.mock(Xyz.class); 
     }
}
```

And then in your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"some.prop=true"}) //you can override properties as well
class MyTest {...}
```

One more thing: you might need to explicitly exclude your TestConfig classes to avoid interfering with other integration tests:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.your.code"}, 
    excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(pattern = ".*TestConfig.*")}) 
class ProdConfig {...}
```

Comment: Thanks,  yes I was talking in integration tests. But why doesn't spring let you simply set a mock instance to a autowired setter?

Comment: If Xyz.class has some spring annotation such as transactionnal Requires new, would the mock inherited the annotation and associated behavior?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Of course you can set a mock instance via a setter, but you will do it after Spring creates all its beans. I.e. in your test class you can have '@Autowired SomeBean b' field and then execute 'b.setAbc(mockAbc)'. But if you want to do *while* Spring creates its beans, then you must provide an overriding mock implementation as a Spring bean.

Comment: Good point about annotations. Well, I think it depends on where  is the annotation. If it is in the production implementation class, then I believe the mock class will not be wrapped with any proxy and will not inherit the transaction stuff. If the annotation is in the interface, I would assume that the mock class would be wrapped with a proxy that would do the transaction stuff (I am not 100% about the last point, it would be better to check with e.g. debugger)